# How to tell when Linux's USB autosuspend has triggered?

Tags: linux, usb

Is there a way to see logs from the USB autosuspend system, to identify when it activates?

I am working on a test harness which repeatedly tests USB devices-under-test. I've seen spurious errors, and suspect [USB autosuspend](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/power-management.txt) to be the culprit. There are various [documented ways](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1140925/how-can-i-disable-usb-autosuspend-on-ubuntu-18-04) to disable autosuspend, but I'm not sure exactly what is effective and what isn't (despite how confident people sound in the comments). My experience matches what was written in [this Arch forum post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=199504) in that `usbcore.autosuspend=-1` doesn't work, but `udev` rules do. However, I'm only working on circumstantial evidence.

In order to better diagnose my problem (and confirm or deny that USB autosuspend contributes to it), I would like to see actual log entries showing whenever USB autosuspend was activated. Does such a log exist? If it matters, I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS with a 4.15.0-213-generic kernel. Thanks!

Comment: " Does such a log exist?" No.